# How to retrieve the source port from a UDP packet while using recvmsg()

Tags: c, linux, udp

I have an application in Linux using C wherein I have created a socket to receive IPv6 UDP packet.

To receive the packet, I use recvmsg() since I need to retrieve the ifindex, which I can get from CMSG_DATA() with the option IPV6_PKTINFO. Now, I need the source port also to be read from the UDP packet. Is there way to get that too?

Answer (score 7):

Sure you can, `recvmsg` looks like this:

```
ssize_t recvmsg(int sockfd, struct msghdr *msg, int flags);
```

And `struct msghdr` contains `msg_name` and `msg_namelen`:

```
struct msghdr {
   void         *msg_name;       /* optional address */
   socklen_t     msg_namelen;    /* size of address */
...
```

So you can do something like this for an IPv4 address:

```
struct sockaddr_in *src = msg->msg_name;
uint16_t port = ntohs(src->sin_port);
```

And adjust accordingly (`sockaddr_in6`) for an IPv6 address.

#### EDIT

I had completely overlooked [`getnameinfo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getnameinfo.html) which R mentions in the comments. This function gets a `struct sockaddr *` which means it doesn't depend on the address family. That function is way powerful but if all you want is the port, you're probably interested in `NI_NUMERICSERV`.

Comment: Or better, use `getnameinfo` to make the code address-family-agnostic.